# REST Services Jersey 2 , Guice, HK , and Message Body Writers and Readers

Tags: rest, jersey, guice, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am migrating REST services from Jersey 1 with Guice to Jersey 2 / Guice
The services / components are of two types:

1. REST Resources
2. Implementations of the `MessageBodyWriter` responses

Injection is used in both types of objects, and......

1. The object is correctly injected in the rest services
2. In the implementations of `MessageBodyWriter` it is unable to find the object to inject.
3. If I don't inject into the `MessageBodyWriter`, it works perfectly ... but I want to inject (I can't find anything logical to not do it)
4. If in the REST object I inject the same object, it works perfectly.

**Sample of MessageBodyWriter :**

```java
@Provider
public class CustomResponseTypeMapper           
      implements MessageBodyWriter<ModelObject> {       

    final ObjectToInject objectInjected;

    @Inject
    public CustomResponseTypeMapper (final ObjectToInject objectToInject) {
        objectInjected = objectToInject;

    }
}
```

Error :

```java
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ObjectToInject)
```

**Guice Servlet Module:**

```java
public class RESTGuiceModuleServlet
       extends ServletModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        try {       
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", GuiceResourceConfigBridge.class.getCanonicalName());          
            params.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", .....packages ....); <== package of rest services and  message writer / readerss       
            bind(ServletContainer.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);           
            serve("/*").with(ServletContainer.class, params);

        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Guice Resourece Config Bridge**

```java
public class GuiceResourceConfigBridge extends ResourceConfig {

    public GuiceResourceConfigBridge() {
        register(new ContainerLifecycleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(Container container) {                                
                ServletContainer servletContainer = (ServletContainer)container;
                InjectionManager injectionManager  = container.getApplicationHandler().getInjectionManager();
                final ServiceLocator locator = injectionManager.getInstance(ServiceLocator.class);
                GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
                final GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = injectionManager.getInstance(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
                Injector injector = (Injector) servletContainer.getServletContext().getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
                guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);

            }
            @Override
            public void onReload(Container container) {
                //onReload
            }
            @Override
            public void onShutdown(Container container) {
                //onShutDown 
            }       
        });
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

- jersey-server :2.29.1
- jersey-hk2 : 2.29.1
- guice-bridge : 2.6.1

Comment: `GuiceResourceConfigBridge`... is this all the code in this class? I'm curious if this is all the app configuration you have. If not, then where is the rest?

Comment: I didn't put the REST resource in this post, there is no problem with that. The bootstraping sequence is  : 1. Guice Listener  2. RESTGuiceModuleServlet  3. Guice Bridge . The REST resources and the Message Boddy Writer and Readers are loaded with this :  params.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", .....packages ....); The problem is that Injection at MessageBodyWriters ( annotated as @provider ) fails.

Comment: Try to just inject the ServiceLocator into the ResourceConfig constructor and forget the `ContainerLifecycleListener`

Comment: Hi , Paul. I tried that, but same issue.

Comment: Apparently the only way works, is creating the Injector and Bridge at the end of the constructor,  and forget to create it at Guice Listener point, or just not using Guice Listener.

Comment: Yea, the Guice listener is how it is done in the previous (1.x) version of Jersey.